# When I get "0.0.0.xx" or "0xxxx"from server ,the html source code will end till the begining of the sequence

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

just like the title says ,

if the server post the message with this format,

> 0.0.0.18

the ie8 will receive this message , but when I check the source code ,it is only a `0` left.When I use a urlencode function to proccess it.The function return a string below.

> %000%00.%000%00.%000%00.%0018

why could it happened ?

If you got some problems in reading my question ,I'm so sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Your url encode string indicates that your string is actually `\00.\00.\00.\018` and not just `0.0.0.18`. I don't know why you have additional `\0` in your string, but this could break the source code view of IE.

Comment: This string is from a program that can get the version of application.I don't know how it insert '\0' in that. I want to take your answer as the best answer.

Comment: You should check if it is known that this program adds the `\0` and if you can tell the program to not include `\0`. If this is not possible or the application you want to version of itself has the `\0` in its version then you need to replace the `\0` with an empty string server side, before you deliver the data to the browser.

Comment: yeah ,I did like you say. but I replaced it when it encoded. And It can run well.Would you answer my question so that I can finish it ?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the proper answer in this page.

> http://www.iss.net/security_center/reference/vuln/HTTP_Zero_Hex_Code.htm